# DROP columns of a table,according to the values in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, alter-table

I have tables like,

**Table A**

```
field1  | field2 | field3 | field4 | field5
```

**Table B**

```
id    | field_names
--------------------
1       field2
2       field3
```

I have to delete field2 and field3 from `Table A` ( means field names in `Table B` ).

Is there any way to drop field names which present in `Table B`. I can't delete the fields manually.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @MitchWheat Can you heip me out?

Comment: A strange response to my questioning why this question got 3 upvotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you need this. anyway MySQL has no such feature. but if you want really do that, execute following query  and execute each rows.

```
SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE TableA DROP ', field_names, ';') FROM TableB;
```

for examples with PHP, (all error check is omitted)

```
$query = "SELECT CONCAT('ALTER TABLE TableA DROP ', field_names, ';') AS stmt FROM TableB;";

$result = mysqli_query($query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    mysqli_query($rows['stmt']);
}
```

Comment: Not only MySQL - I'm pretty sure **NO** RDBMS has this functionality.  Given that it's outside of the standard and all...

Answer (score 3):

This would help:

```
SELECT @s := CONCAT('ALTER TABLE tableA DROP COLUMN ', GROUP_CONCAT(field_names SEPARATOR ', DROP COLUMN '), ';') FROM tableB;
PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
EXECUTE @s;
```

Answer (score 1):

First create a procedure:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE deleteTableAColumns()
BEGIN
    DECLARE columnToDelete VARCHAR(16);
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE columnsToDeleteCur CURSOR FOR SELECT field_names FROM tableB;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;
    OPEN columnsToDeleteCur;
    read_loop: LOOP 
        FETCH columnsToDeleteCur INTO columnToDelete;
        IF done THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;
        SET @dropColumnQuery = CONCAT('ALTER TABLE tableA DROP ', columnToDelete, ';');
        PREPARE dropColumnQueryStatement FROM @dropColumnQuery;
        EXECUTE dropColumnQueryStatement;
        DEALLOCATE PREPARE dropColumnQueryStatement; 
    END LOOP;
    CLOSE columnsToDeleteCur;
END
//
DELIMITER ;
```

Then call the procedure whenever you want to execute it:

```
CALL deleteTableAColumns();
```